# Cannot connect to amazon web services database

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have made a website and it is currently hosted on Netfirms.

The following is my code that I'm using to connect to my amazon web services database:

```
<?php
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re expericing connection problems.';
mysql_connect('xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com','myusername','mypassword') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('invest') or die($connect_error);
?>
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (111) in
>   /hermes/bosnaweb03b/b2442/nf.liangbros/triumph/core/database/connect.php
>   on line 6

What can I do to resolve this? Is it something wrong with AWS or is there something I can set on netfirms and/or AWS? I made the dev website and tested it using easyPHP on my localhost and everything works (successfully connects to amazon web services) but after uploading all my files onto my netfirms host, it cannot connect to AWS database. I need this site up and running before end of month December, please help! Thanks!

I have tried to change the security group on my AWS database to the following:
netfirms (sg-ce2d23aa)
For this security group, I set the following:

[inbound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhv1V.png)

The following is a snapshot of my database on AWS:
[AWS database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTtB5.png)

Comment: Do you have any outbound firewall rules on your web hosting server that would block connections on 3306? Also, you should be using mysqli or pdo instead of mysql. Mysql is considered deprecated and has been removed in PHP 7.

Comment: I called them just now and they said there are no outbound firewall rules set. Yes I will change it to PDO after I get this working. using mysql or PDO wouldn't affect the connection though right?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Can you use the mysql tools on your hosting server? If so are you able to connect using `mysql -h hostname -u username -p`? Also, its not ideal to be connecting to a database hosted in another datacenter. Every query will get latency equal to the latency between datacenters. If you do alot of queries, this can add up, significantly.

Comment: There are no mysql tools on netfirms (netfirms is a really cheap host, not too many features) and yes I understand that, but this is only for a testing link so I can show my client the site before I post the files onto their server.  Maybe I will just purchase another host and a test domain and try that? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: If you have an aws account, you can quickly set up a t2.nano or t2.micro instance if all you need to do is test it. Before setting up the site. but after installing all the packages, create an AMI for the stack you use so you can set up others later more quickly.

Comment: Does that mean setting up a LAMP stack instance? There are a gazillion things on AWS and I'm not sure which one to choose.

Comment: I used elastic beanstalk to create it and everything works! thank you for all your help :) cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Your RDS has a security group, and it's also part of a VPC that has it's own security group. Right now your RDS allows all traffic that can reach it, but I would be willing to bet that your VPC security group does not allow the traffic coming or going to pass to the subnet. I would also recommend using the MySQL/Aurora (3306) vs the All Traffic option, then set the source to 0.0.0.0/0. You also need to check your EC2 instance security group to insure it has the right inbound and outbound settings that you need.

Comment: It's not a security group issue. From the error shown, it can't be. Security group misconfiguration would cause the error to include `(110)` (connection timed out), and not `(111)` (connection refused).  Security groups silently discard denied traffic -- causing the denied connection to time out -- they don't actively reset connections, and that would be necessary for the system error code to be 111.  That, or the target host being up and online without the MySQL Server daemon running -- highly unlikely with RDS.  This is almost certainly firewalling at the originating side of the connection.

Comment: What is this second security group you are talking about? The security group assigned to the RDS instance is a "VPC security group". VPCs themselves don't have security groups that control VPC-wide traffic like you are indicating. Perhaps you are confusing security groups and network ACLs?